# Is it possible to access variable of the parent within child element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue 2. I have this component:

```
<AccordionItem :item-title="someName">

    <div v-if="item-title=='Ann'"></div>

</AccordionItem>
```

Is it possible to access `item-title` variable within the child element?

Comment: Within the scope of the parent component, you can just use `someName`

Comment: Acordionitem can have multiple values, I need to check if accordion has a specific value. That why I need to check item-title.

Comment: But `item-title` and `someName` are the same in your example

Comment: Are you asking about [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)? If so, there's good documentation and a [bunch of posts already on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66457453/what-exactly-is-scoped-slot-in-vuejs). If not, please clarify your question

Answer (score -1):

If you are passing a `:item-title` attribute to your component `AccordionItem`, so that you can get its value you can use itemTitle. Don't forget that the component `AccordionItem` must have itemTitle as prop.

```js
...
props: {
    itemTitle: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
},
...
created() {},
```